# Converting a string with html entities to an array in the same order

Tags: php, regex

I have a string in this form :

```
<strong>dsds </strong><em>sdqsd </em><span style='text-decoration: underline;'>test</span>
```

and i want to put it in an associative array :

```
array('strong' => 'dsds' , 'em' => 'sdqsd' , 'underline' => 'test');
```

in a way that the order of elements int this array have to be the same as their order in the string .

which means if i have for example :

```
<span style='text-decoration: underline;'>test</span><strong>dsds </strong><em>sdqsd </em>
```

i get :

```
 array( 'underline' => 'test', 'strong' => 'dsds' , 'em' => 'sdqsd');
```

I tried doing it by using strpos in a loop but that's a lot of iterations specialy if i have a big string, so is there a simpler way using regex ?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not clear about how deep you want to go.  What is the expected results of: `<strong><em>abc</em><span style = "text-decoration: underline">def</span></strong>` ?  A RegEx would be unsuitable for this, you will need an HTML parser instead.

Comment: This definitely falls under the umbrella of parsing HTML with regex, which as we all know (obligatory link) [you should not do](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348)...

Comment: thanks for the suggestion , i will try php's DOMDocument but still i will have a problem with preserving the order

Answer (score 1):

1, You can use tag names as array indexes only in case you have only one tage of each type per parsed HTML statement.

2, Maybe this library will help: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

3, Or create custom parser using regular expression. That's solution that I really wont suggest because of big CPU performance requirements.